# Add more views in a layout programmatically in Android

Tags: android, layoutparams

I'm doing a paint application where in I already have a button. But I want to add another button. When I do, it's overlapping the previous button.

I'm kinda new to LayoutParams so I need your guidance in here. Please do check the code I'm working on:

```
  public class MyTouchEventView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
private Path circlePath = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public Button btnSave;
public LayoutParams params;
public LayoutParams params2;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(15f);

    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);


    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");
    btnSave = new Button(context);
    btnSave.setText("Save Image");

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);
            btnSave.setLayoutParams(params);



    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // resets the screen
            path.reset();
            // Calls the onDraw() method
            postInvalidate();
        }
    });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // resets the screen
            path.reset();
            // Calls the onDraw() method
            postInvalidate();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
}
```

**My MainActivity:**

```
  public class DrawingBrush extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyTouchEventView tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);

    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset,  tv.params);
            addContentView(tv.btnSave,  tv.params);
    }
```

Guys can you help me figure out what I'm missing in here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple Views, then you need to use a Layout to wrap them. In your case you could use a FrameLayout instead of the View to inherit from. Add the Button directly in there to it.

```
public class MyTouchEventView extends FrameLayout {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();
private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
private Path circlePath = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public Button btnSave;
public FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
public FrameLayout.LayoutParams params2;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    ...

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");
    ...

    params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);
    addView(btnReset);


    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
}
```

And btw: you can set only one content view, so calling `setContentView()` multiple times just replaces it.

Comment: If you don't want them to overlap, then you could use a LinearLayout. Add first your custom view and then the button. More information about Layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Hi simosays, I changed it to LinearLayout and it's not overlapping anymore, but the problem now is I can't draw on the canvas. What's wrong?

Comment: Make one View that only draws your custom stuff and does not contain anything else. Then make a LinearLayout and add this custom View as well as the Buttons to it. But this is actually another question, so please create a new Thread for it.

Comment: this is the link of my new questionL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360848/cant-draw-on-canvas/16362239?noredirect=1#comment23445048_16362239