# Drawing a canvas in activity with predefined layout

Tags: java, android

I want to make some motion on a layout. So, I made an activity with my layout with two images at center. Now, i want to draw a canvas in same activity to show some motion. How to draw a canvas on same activity with predefined layout??

Comment: Please post your code so far as the description isn't enough to really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah sorry for that. Actually I made a layout with two ImageView and set it to my activity by setContentView(R.layout.name). Now, i want to draw a canvas on this layout and animate it through code(like simple translation).

Comment: Do it explain what i want to ask? xD

Comment: Yes. This question seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360848/cant-draw-on-canvas

Comment: Thanks man.. But the I want the view to be at center of main layout. How can i retrieve the coordinates of the center of the main layout??

Comment: edit your code and add your layout.

Comment: can i move an image without using canvas?? I am confused :S